# Probability question in which balls are selected with replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Four balls are to be randomly selected, with replacement, from an urn that contains $20$ balls numbered $1$ through $20$. If the random variable $X$ is the largest numbered ball selected, find the following:

$a)$ Probability that $X$ takes on each of its possible values.

$b)$ Probability that $X$ is strictly greater than $10$.

---

My answers are:

$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ a) \ \ \ \frac{i^3}{20^4} \ \ \ \ \ \ i=1,2,\ldots,20$$
$$b) \ \ \ \ 1-\frac{10^4}{20^4}$$

Could someone please verify these? I am a little unsure of my answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) is not correct, you haven't accounted for the ordering of the balls. Try summing the probabilities from $i = 1$ to $i = 20$ and you won't get 1. (b) looks fine. A hint would be if you can work out the probability that $X > n$ for any $n$, you can quite easily work out the probability that $X = n$.

Comment: I used the hint and arrived at $\frac{i^4-(i-1)^4}{20^4}$. Correct now?

Comment: Yes, that's what I got

Comment: And the probabilities add up to $1$ as well. Thanks for the help!